# Windows Explorer: How to avoid that a "slow" double click on a file opens "renaming"

Tags: windows-explorer

For me, one annoying thing in Windows Explorer is that a "slow" double-click on a file or folder will be interpreted as "rename."

Is there a way to disable that single-click rename feature in Windows Explorer or some other tweak which could help? If I really need to rename a file, I could hit the F2 key or open the context menu anyway.

Comment: Just for laughs: on a Mac, things are even worse: to change a file name or directory name, hit Return. Really. To open it, hit Command-o (or Command-Arrow Down). I love my Mac, but for a few things. :-)

Comment: Yes, that is different on the Mac. It was a little confusing for me too, coming from the Windows world.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your mouse should have a double-click speed in its configuration.

[image]

Comment: How does this help in a "rename problem"?

Comment: @JosefSábl I guess any click recognized as a double click won't open the rename thing. But even setting double-click speed to the lowest setting means that click-clicks slower than than will trigger the rename functionality...